# angular mat-grid and mat-card not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let boat of BOATS">
        <mat-card></mat-card>
        {{boat.name}}
        <img mat-card-image [src]="boat.img">
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export interface Tile {
  cols: number;
  rows: number;
  text: string;
}

export interface boat {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  img: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-boats',
  templateUrl: './boats.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./boats.component.css']
})

export class BoatsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  BOATS: boat[] = [
    {id: 1, name: "FreiFjord", img: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6n30OrfVjAS0mXcTN6xoZSOpFxuxJxXYLbPELBKZZJg&s"},
    {id: 2, name: "Torvang", img: "\torhusshipping\torvang.jpg"},
  
  ]

  tiles: Tile[] = [
    {text: this.BOATS[1].name, cols: 1, rows: 1},
    {text: this.BOATS[2].name, cols: 1, rows:1},
  ]


}
```

I'm trying to make a `mat-grid` with `mat-cards` inside, but I'm struggling to extract and display information from a list of properties in my `.ts file`. it worked once, but I changed something without pushing it to GitHub first and now I can't get it working again.

Comment: can you upload a minimal reproducible example to stackblitz (or anything similar)?

Comment: @LielFridman https://github.com/2mastang1/torhusshipping is this good enough?